# Need to replace hyphen (-) for converted opportunities last character

Tags: workflow

Requirement is to replace the hyphen(-) with space for opportunities that are having '-' after the opportunity name. 
Example:
Test-opp- : It should replaces as Test-opp

I am using substitue function to replace hyphen for opportunity name.But it is not working as expected
substitue(Name,'-','') in workflow rule field update

Comment: Considering the method you wrote is a typo here, it's SUBSTITUTE. Also could you please check if the workflow is activated, and the method you wrote would replace every occurrence of the hyphen, if you want to remove the last one only (as your example), you should use LEFT(Name, LEN(Name)- 1)

Comment: Thank you Aditya Vijay. You solution solved my problem

Comment: Glad it helped, adding that as the answer, might help others as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the method you wrote is a typo here, it's SUBSTITUTE.

Also could you please check if the workflow is activated, and the method you wrote would replace every occurrence of the hyphen, if you want to remove the last one only (as your example), you should use 
`LEFT(Name, LEN(Name)- 1)`